# I can't make 'elif' 'or' relation

Tags: python

```
writer.writerow([
  i,
  username,
  member.id,
  name,
  group.title,
  'yes' elif (time.time()-(member.status.was_online).timestamp() <=86400 or member.status, (UserStatusRecently,UserStatusOnline)) else 'no'
])
```

**after typing this**

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**I get an error, help me**

Comment: `elif` normally follows an `if`.

Comment: Can you explain what you are attempting to do? it is not clear from the code.

Comment: `elif` is short terms for `else if`. Where is the `if`?

Comment: (time.time()-(member.status.was_online).timestamp() <=86400 ***OR***member.status, (UserStatusRecently,UserStatusOnline)) I just want to print 'yes' if either case 1 or 2 happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want `if` rather than `elif`, and so you want this:

```
writer.writerow([
  i,
  username,
  member.id,
  name,
  group.title,
  'yes' if (time.time()-(member.status.was_online).timestamp() <=86400 or member.status in (UserStatusRecently,UserStatusOnline)) else 'no'
])
```

I also changed the second test in the conditional by replacing `,` with `in`.  It didn't make sense to me the way you had it.

Answer (score 0):

`elif` can't be by itself it's a secondary option of the first which is the `if` is not true.

Try changing the `elif` with an `if`:

```
writer.writerow([
  i,
  username,
  member.id,
  name,
  group.title,
  'yes' if (time.time()-(member.status.was_online).timestamp() <=86400 or member.status (UserStatusRecently,UserStatusOnline)) else 'no'
])
```